# how to make a select query on all weekdays/ all month / all hours and showing 0 when values don't exist

Tags: sql

In sql I want to show statistics data, so I'd like to show sums from all weekdays, by showing 0 for the weekday that doesn't exist. Same goes with month, hours, years....

The problem is that there is no table to join to to get the missing days.
Is there a clean method to do this?

Thank you

**Edit** : 
The DB and data is irrelevent but I'm using Oracle DB and Mysql, simply put if i want to do

```
SELECT SUM(SALES) FROM SALES_TABLE WHERE SALES_DATE BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2 GROUP BY WEEKDAY
```

how to change this to get 0 for example on sundays, and not get SATURDAY :4, MONDAY:4

Comment: could you please post a data sample for us?

Comment: I edited my question, In fact i want exactly what Phil Cairns answered, but if possible without creating tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a table with day names in it, and then do a left join on that table.

It'd help to have a look at the table structure you have, but if I was going to do it, I'd do something like the following:

```
create table stats (dayname varchar(3), "value" int);
create table daynames (dayname varchar(3));
insert into stats values ('Sun', 5), ('Mon', 4), ('Wed', 13), ('Sun', 3), ('Tue', 5), ('Sat', 5), ('Mon', 32);
insert into daynames values ('Sun'),('Mon'),('Tue'),('Wed'),('Thu'),('Fri'),('Sat');

select daynames.dayname, sum("value") from daynames left outer join stats on stats.dayname=daynames.dayname group by daynames.dayname;

| dayname | sum |
|---------+-----|
| Fri     |     |
| Mon     | 36  |
| Sat     | 5   |
| Sun     | 8   |
| Thu     |     |
| Tue     | 5   |
| Wed     | 13  |
```

You'll have nulls for the sums on dates that aren't represented in your data, but you can convert them to zeros, depending on your database server.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I want, but is there no other way than to create a table for weekdays? because then I'll have to create a table for day of month, hours of day, month of year...

Comment: Creating the tables is definitely the cleanest approach; otherwise you will have to populate the values through a while() loop, creating inefficient queries.  By joining to the tables you can use an index and will find it runs much faster.

Comment: I guess this is the best way, thank you. one more question how do u handle day of month (28 feb / 30 and 31)?

Comment: I'd be seriously considering writing a program for this, rather than trying to get it all done in SQL. It comes down to a trade-off between your skills, the time you have available, and the tools you have at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way to do it without creating a table would be to use CASE statements inside of a SUM. Most likely you will take a large performance hit doing this but I haven't tested it and for a smallish set of data you shouldn't see to much impact. It will also put everything into one record instead of 7 different records

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(SALES_DATE) = 1 THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) AS SUNDAY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(SALES_DATE) = 2 THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) AS MONDAY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(SALES_DATE) = 3 THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) AS TUESDAY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(SALES_DATE) = 4 THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) AS WEDNESDAY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(SALES_DATE) = 5 THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) AS THURSDAY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(SALES_DATE) = 6 THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) AS FRIDAY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(SALES_DATE) = 7 THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) AS SATURDAY
FROM SALES_TABLE 
WHERE SALES_DATE BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2
```